# Alfresco Share constraint default empty value

Tags: select, constraints, share, alfresco

i have a simple question.
Is there a simple config file or line that can be edited in order to achieve this:
I need that constraints from Alfresco content model have an empty field (like "unselected") in Advanced Search and Edit Metadata forms.
So a constraint of:

```
<constraint name="custom:customList" type="LIST">
            <parameter name="allowedValues">
                <list>
                    <value>first type</value>
                    <value>second type</value>
                </list>
            </parameter>
        </constraint>
```

I need to view these in a "SELECT" form but with the first selection empty, like:

```
   <select>
          <value></value>
          <value>first type</value>
          <value>second type</value>
   </select>
```

Hope I made that clear.
P.S. I don't want to insert a  in the custom content model XML file. There should be another way to achieve this.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the presentation logic, i.e. customize or create a new form control template. The default one is implemented in [selectone.ftl](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/web-framework-commons/config/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/selectone.ftl), you can customize it or start from it for a brand new control template which you can later [assign to your metadata field](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Forms_Examples#Providing_A_Custom_Form_Template) in the forms configuration.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it, I just created a custom selectone.ftl and added a <option></option> before the constraint list, so there is always an empty value in the selection.
Thanks

Comment: how do you implement the custom *.ftl you made?